# Cant figure out this function

Tags: javascript, function, filter

**userHasVisitedParkOnWishlist**

This function takes in the list of users and two usernames. If the first user has visited any of the parks represented by the second user's wishlist, return true. Otherwise, return false.

```
const users = {
    "karah.branch3": {
      visited: [1],
      wishlist: [4, 6],
    },
    "dwayne.m55": {
      visited: [2, 5, 1],
      wishlist: [],
    },
    thiagostrong1: {
      visited: [5],
      wishlist: [6, 3, 2],
    },
    "don.kim1990": {
      visited: [2, 6],
      wishlist: [1],
    },
  };


function userHasVisitedParkOnWishlist(users, userA, userB) { 
  const result = Object.keys(users).filter(wish => wish.visited === userA);
  return result.some(wish => { userA.visited > userB.visited});
}

// Example calls:
userHasVisitedParkOnWishlist(users, "dwayne.m55", "karah.branch3"); //> true 
userHasVisitedParkOnWishlist(users, "karah.branch3", "dwayne.m55"); //> false
```

Comment: And what is the issue?  How are you calling this function?

Comment: `visited` will never equal `userA`.  `visited` is an array, and `userA` is implied to be a single thing, not an array.  And arrays cannot be compared using greater than/less than.

Comment: its only returning false when i need it to return true for one of the calls, is there a way that i can add a picture of what its calling ?

Comment: Can you answer my second question?

Comment: userHasVisitedParkOnWishlist(users, "dwayne.m55", "karah.branch3"); //> true
userHasVisitedParkOnWishlist(users, "karah.branch3", "dwayne.m55"); //> false

Comment: Since dwayne's whishlist is empty, the function will never return true when dwayne is the second argument. At least that is the logic expressed in your very first paragraph. Not sure what your question is. There isn't any in your "question".

Comment: `wishlist` is never referenced by the code.

Comment: this is the return. should return true if the first user has visited any locations on the second user's wishlist, I don't know exactly what it is calling because it doesnt specify in the program I just havent gotten past this last portion for the past couple of hours

Comment: Is this your code? I mean, did you write it?

Comment: I wrote the function, its for a assignment so the object users was already in the files, I just have to write a code to do what its asking for

Comment: Ok, can you explain why you want the second case to return true? Looking only at the data, it should return false.

Comment: So for the assignment it should return true if the first user has visited any locations on the second users wishlist, the second return should return false if the first user has not visited any locations on the second user's wishlist

Comment: Okay, based on that description, the second case should return true.  The second user's wishlist contains `1`, and the first user has visited `1`.  Right?

Comment: yeah, sorry I'm still new to javascript I've only been learning for a month

Comment: so if the user has the number in their visited and the next user has that number in their wishlist it would return true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `userHasVisitedParkOnWishlist(users, "dwayne.m55", "karah.branch3")` -> this should be `false`, not `true`
2. You just have to check if `userB`'s wishlist `includes` at least one element of `userA`'s visited list

```js
const users = {
  "karah.branch3": {
    visited: [1],
    wishlist: [4, 6],
  },
  "dwayne.m55": {
    visited: [2, 5, 1],
    wishlist: [],
  },
  thiagostrong1: {
    visited: [5],
    wishlist: [6, 3, 2],
  },
  "don.kim1990": {
    visited: [2, 6],
    wishlist: [1],
  },
};


function userHasVisitedParkOnWishlist(users, userA, userB) {
  return users[userA]["visited"].some(v => users[userB]["wishlist"].includes(v))
}

// Example calls:
const a = userHasVisitedParkOnWishlist(users, "dwayne.m55", "karah.branch3"); //> true -> NO THIS SHOULD BE FALSE!!!
const b = userHasVisitedParkOnWishlist(users, "karah.branch3", "dwayne.m55"); //> false
const c = userHasVisitedParkOnWishlist(users, "dwayne.m55", "don.kim1990"); //> true

console.log(a, b, c)
```

If you want to make it look a bit more thought through, then you could use a HOF (Higher Order Function) approach:

```js
const users = {
  "karah.branch3": {
    visited: [1],
    wishlist: [4, 6],
  },
  "dwayne.m55": {
    visited: [2, 5, 1],
    wishlist: [],
  },
  thiagostrong1: {
    visited: [5],
    wishlist: [6, 3, 2],
  },
  "don.kim1990": {
    visited: [2, 6],
    wishlist: [1],
  },
};

// HOF - returns a function (that expects two arguments)
const userHasVisitedParkOnWishlist = (users) => {
  return (userA, userB) => {
    return users[userA]["visited"].some(v => users[userB]["wishlist"].includes(v))
  }
}

// set the HOF with the users argument
const hasVisitedParks = userHasVisitedParkOnWishlist(users)

// Now you only have to call the function with 2 arguments -
// the users object is "already accounted for"
const a = hasVisitedParks("dwayne.m55", "karah.branch3"); //> false
const b = hasVisitedParks("karah.branch3", "dwayne.m55"); //> false
const c = hasVisitedParks("dwayne.m55", "don.kim1990"); //> true

console.log(a, b, c)
```